# Scaffolding ModelView creates underlying database tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I'm trying to use ViewModels for the first time using AutoMapper. I have two models:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ItemOption> ItemOptions { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class ItemOption
{
    public int ItemOptionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Which I have turned into two ViewModels:

```
public class ItemDetailViewModel
{
    public int ItemDetailViewModelId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ItemDetailItemOptionViewModel> ItemOptions { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDetailItemOptionViewModel
{
    public int ItemDetailItemOptionViewModelId { get; set; }
    public int ItemOptionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }

}
```

I then set the following in my application start-up:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemDetailViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ItemOption, ItemDetailItemOptionViewModel>();
```

Finally I scaffolded my ItemDetailViewModel:

[image]

I then built my project and added a new Item through /Item/Create

I had a look in the database expecting to see that I would have an entry in the Item table, but instead I have ItemDetailViewModel and ItemDetailItemOptionViewModel tables, which I wasn't expecting and the data is is ItemDetailViewModel.

I assume I have done something wrong with my scaffolding? How do I scaffold off the ViewModel without making it part of the main business models?

**Further Details**

If it isn't possible to scaffold the controller with a ViewModel, then how do I reference the ViewModel in the controller and save changes back to the database?

For example what would the following change to once I remove ItemDetailViewModel from the db context?

```
    //
    // POST: /Item/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ItemDetailViewModel itemdetailviewmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ItemDetailViewModels.Add(itemdetailviewmodel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(itemdetailviewmodel);
    }
```

**Further Details [2]**

So am I correct that my Index/Details should work as so or is there a better way of doing it?

```
    //
    // GET: /Item/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = db.Items.ToList();
        var itemdetailviewmodel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ItemDetailViewModel>(items);
        return View(itemdetailviewmodel);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Item/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        ItemDetailViewModel itemdetailviewmodel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ItemDetailViewModel>(db.Items.Find(id));
        if (itemdetailviewmodel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(itemdetailviewmodel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffolding is not that intelligent. The standard controller scaffolding template is creating a DbContext with the controller model and presumes you are working with the DB models, not view models and it does not use Automapper. So you'll need to either not use scaffolding, or check what it has done before using it.

And nothing is wrong with the way you use scaffolding, it is just not supposed to do what you expect.

**Update** this is how you do this without scaffolding

```
// Without Automapper
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ItemDetailViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var item = new Item() 
        {
            Active = model.Active,
            ItemCode = model.ItemCode,
            Name = model.Name,
            ItemOptions = // code to convert from List<ItemDetailItemOptionViewModel> to List<ItemOption>
        }
        db.Items.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}


// with Automapper - not recommended by author of Automapper
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ItemDetailViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var item = Automapper.Mapper.Map<Item>(model);

        db.Items.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

You'll need to modify your DbContext to have `IDbSet<Item> Items` instead of `IDbSet<ItemDetailViewModels> ItemDetailViewModels`.

Automapper was created to map from Domain Models to View Models and not the other way. I have done that for a while, but this is troublesome and causes subtle bugs and other maintenance problems. Even Jimmy Bogard himself [says you should not map from view models to domain models](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/).

Comment: So it sounds like scaffolding isn't the way to go! However I am now a little confused as to how to link the database and ViewModel - I've added further details to my question.

Comment: no, seems like scaffolding is not always the way to go. See my update.

Comment: Thanks for your help - one more question then I think I've got it. I have added the Index/Details method to my question - have I gone about these in the correct way?

Comment: `Index` is perfect. With `Edit` I'd get the `Item` into a separate variable and check that for null, then if it is not null - map to the view model and return to the view (your code would work, but just for readability sake). Also can add `using Automapper;` into the start of controller and  loose `Automapper.` from both mapping statements. Otherwise you've got the idea!

Comment: When doing the Index I get: Exception Details: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Comment: You need to add mapping from `Item` to `ItemDetailsViewModel`: `Mapper.CreateMap<ItemDetailViewModel,Item>();` to Automapper configuration.

Comment: So the two mappings in my question are the wrong way around? I have just changed it to `Mapper.CreateMap<ItemDetailViewModel,Item>();` which gets called in Application_Start(). I've added breakpoints, so I know it's definitely getting hit, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Ah, I see. You are trying to map `List<Item>` to `ItemDetailViewModel`. And this mapping does not exist. Change `Index` action to do `var itemdetailviewmodel = Mapper.Map<List<ItemDetailViewModel>>(items);` so you are mapping from List<> to List<>, not from List<> to object

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44112/discussion-between-joseph-and-trailmax)